# elemento CSS pierde efecto despues de refrescar la pagina

Tags: html, css, asp.net

En una pagina tengo la siguente estructura:

Div que ocupa 70% - otro div que ocupa 30%.
Los quise separar por una imagen, eliminando asi la linea fija de separacion.
Esa imagen que separa los 2 div's pierde sus efectos de posicion css cuando refresco la pagina, despues si voy al css y borro/vuelvo a pegar su altura por ejemplo, se vuelve a posicionarse bien.

[image: Separador 'hojas' antes del refresh]

[image: Separador 'hojas' despues del refresh]

```css
body {
}

#divCampo {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

#divCampo #campo{
 min-height:100%;

 background-size:cover;

    position: absolute;
    top:0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

#divCesped {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left: 70%;
}

#divCesped #cesped{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    
}

#separador {
    z-index: 500;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 68%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/siluetas.css" />

    <title>_</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div id="divCampo">
            <img id="campo" src="images/campo.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="divCesped">
            <img id="cesped" src="images/cesped2.png" />
        </div>

        <img id="separador" src="images/separador.png"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo probé con las imágenes, pero la solución que propongo es:

1) Para que el absolute tenga efecto, necesitas un div (wrapper) que englobe a los divs que tienen imagenes con position absolute, y que tenga position relative. (Sí son dos, pero yo agregué uno para el divisor).

2) El img es un tag de tipo inline, es como si escribieras texto, para posicionarlo hay que ponerlo dentro de un div u otro elemento de bloque  también con position absolute. (Sino al img hay que ponerle inline-block como display)

Abajo hice las modificaciones al código.

```css
body {
}

#divCampo {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

#divCampo #campo{
 min-height:100%;

 background-size:cover;

    position: absolute;
    top:0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
}

#divCesped {
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left: 70%;
}

#divCesped #cesped{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    
}

#separador {
    
}

#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}

#divSeparador{
    z-index: 500;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 68%;
    width: 4%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/siluetas.css" />

    <title>_</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div class="wrapper">    
        <div id="divCampo">
            <img id="campo" src="images/campo.png" />
        </div>

        <div id="divCesped">
            <img id="cesped" src="images/cesped2.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="divSeparador">
           <img id="separador" src="images/separador.png"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **1) Para que el absolute tenga efecto, necesitas un div (wrapper) que englobe a los divs que tienen imagenes con position absolute, y que tenga position relative. (Sí son dos, pero yo agregué uno para el divisor).**

No es necesario el div wrapper, ya que mi form abarca a todos los div's. La posicion absoluta funciona bien. Mi css estaba bien, solo que tuve que cerrar Visual Estudio y volverlo a abrir, despues me andaba bien todo.

No se que le estara pasando a mi computadora.

Gracias por tu ayuda igual.

Comment: No vi que el form esté posicionado como relative (o algo distinto a static). Puede que te funcione, pero no esta bien. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Voy a tomar en cuenta tu comentario y seguramente implemente tu codigo, por las dudas, ya que mi experiencia en css es casi nula. Un saludo